# Error on checking check box on kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a check box column to my kendo grid like this.

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' />").Width("5%").Title("<input id='chkAll' class='checkAllCls' type='checkbox'/>");
```

The grid populates properly and when I check the check box, there is an error as shown below.

```
VM1173:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'd0b3c3ae-082b-468d-94ce-ae000093cfb8')
    at init._persistSelectedRows (<anonymous>:62:19817)
    at init.select (<anonymous>:62:18472)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:39:26)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.dispatch (<anonymous>:5237:27)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.elemData.handle (<anonymous>:5044:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [columns.Select()](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/checkbox-selection)?

The following link allows you to [bind your model to the selected checkbox](https://www.telerik.com/forums/bind-select-column-to-model-field) on load.

---

Alternatively bind your checkbox to a column in your model using template notation
This is the default template I use, you can customize it to your liking.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.BoolProperty).Title("Is Checked?").Width(30).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' #=BoolProperty? checked='checked' : '' # />");
```

It works with inline and in-cell edit.

And using [this code snippet](http://dojo.telerik.com/akuJa), works with header templates to check all checkboxes

Comment: Columns.Select() is working for me.